# How to call a user defined Matlab from Java using matlabcontrol.jar

Tags: java, matlab, proxy, user-defined-functions, matlab-deployment

I am trying to call a user defined Matlab Function(M file) which takes 3 arguments(Java Strings) from my Java application which is developed in Eclipse. At the moment I am able to call `proxy.eval` and `proxy.feval` methods with the functions/commands like `disp` or `sqr`. But when i try to invoke a user-defined function it says on the matlab console that there is no such function defined like that and on the Java console `MatlabInvocationException` occurs.

Then I tried with a simple user-defined function which takes no arguments and just has single line `disp('Hello')` but still the result is same. So I think rather than a type conversion problem there is something wrong with how user-defined functions are getting invoked.

Please can anyone help me soon? I am meeting the deadline very soon for this project. I would be so thankful if someone can come up with a solution. (Mr Joshuwa Kaplan, is there any guide on solving an issue like this in your posts? I tried but found nothing)

Thanks in advance

Comment: To make the question clear, the OP is using [matlabcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/), an API to call MATLAB from Java programs (relies upon the undocumented [JMI](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/))

Comment: Just FYI, [matconsolectl](https://github.com/diffplug/matconsolectl) is an actively-maintained fork of matlabcontrol.

Answer (score 11):

You must have any user-defined m-files on the **MATLAB search path**, just as if you were working normally inside MATLAB.

I tested with the following example:

#### C:\some\path\myfunc.m

```
function myfunc()
    disp('hello from MYFUNC')
end
```

#### HelloWorld.java

```
import matlabcontrol.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
    {
         // create proxy
         MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options =
            new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                .build();
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

        // call builtin function
        proxy.eval("disp('hello world')");

        // call user-defined function (must be on the path)
        proxy.eval("addpath('C:\\some\\path')");
        proxy.feval("myfunc");
        proxy.eval("rmpath('C:\\some\\path')");

        // close connection
        proxy.disconnect();
    }
}
```

We compile and run the Java program:

```
javac -cp matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar HelloWorld.java
java -cp ".;matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar" HelloWorld
```

a MATLAB session will open up, and display the output:

```
hello world
hello from MYFUNC
```

You could also add your folder to the path once, then persist it using SAVEPATH. That way you won't have to do it each time.

Comment: It was really quick and accurate. I had to remove the proxy.eval("rmpath('C:\\some\\path')");
as in my code, i think that is because the of the computation i have to do in matlab and it takes a little bit of time. And i am very much thankful to you. i tried this more than 2 days continuously. so this is a very big help for me. once again Thank you very much and appreciate your effort in this.Cheers Amro :) :):)