# How to open a matlab session from java and execute matlab scripts

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment, processbuilder

I have a matlab script that takes an input mat file and produces an output file.
Currently I have a shell script that is able to execute this script.

I am executing this script from Java using `ProcessBuilder` class and all is working well.
I need to perform the matlab script execution very often from java and each time script executes the mcr process is created, script executes  and mcr terminates.

i like to have the MCR process open and  have a matlab session open towards java , so that same process is kept alive so i can execute scripts multiple times in  the same session.

I find  matlabcontrol seems to be suitablefor this. 
How to  configure the `MatlabProxyFactory` with the MCR location and  LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
which i am setting in my shell script and execute my script in a same session?

I also came across a tool MATLAB JA Builder but i cannot use this at the moment as its not Free.

Thanks!

Comment: check out my answer to a similar question: [How to call a user defined Matlab function(M file) from java(Eclipse) using matlabcontrol.jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212467/how-to-call-a-user-defined-matlab-functionm-file-from-javaeclipse-using-matl/7212651#7212651)

Comment: Thank You Amro, i wil test this. One question though- how does matlab control know the matlab runtime  home to invoke it ?. i have made a default mcr installation and matlab isn't on system class path.

Comment: just to be clear here, [matlabcontrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) requires a live installation of MATLAB and does not work with only the [MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f12-999353.html). That said, if you have a non-default MATLAB installation location, you need to explicitly specify that information. Consult the docs for [matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder.html) for more information

Comment: many thanks for the reply. i only have got the MCR and not Matlab..Is there any java library to achieve similar thing?

Comment: If you had access to the MATLAB Builder JA, you could build a java library from your MATLAB script (as opposed to an executable which I assume you currently have). It would expose initialization methods to be called once at the beginning, and then you would call the computation methods as many times as you want (without the overhead of creating/tearing down the MCR session multiple times).. Please consult the documentation of the respective products

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `matlabcontrol` I don't think you need the shell script, just tell it the name of the m-file you want to be run. If you want to keep the shell script in conjunction with a `ProcessBuilder`, you have to start the process once and keep a reference to its input stream. When you want a command executed, you write it that stream. Also, you have to keep a thread alive to empty the output and error streams of Matlab, otherwise they will get full and Matlab will hang. If you want to go with this, I recommend looking at the source of [this](http://code.google.com/p/rcaller/) project (which I am a contributor to). The class you are interested in is RCaller. It does more or less the same, except it invokes R and not matlab.