# How to call Matlab functions from Java using matlabcontrol without starting new session every time?

Tags: java, matlab

I am using matlabcontrol to call Matlab functions from Java

My code works well, but it opens new Matlab session whenever I run my code in Java.
I edited according to Javadoc, but I guess I missed something.

I also tried this with/without 'proxy.disconnect()', but it still opens new Matlab session.
Any hint will be very helpful. I am stuck..

below is my Java code

```
import matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabInvocationException;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxy;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory;
import matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactoryOptions;

public class callSaliencymap {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
{
    //Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
    MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
    MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

    MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
    .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
    .setHidden(true)
    .build();

    factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);




    //Create proxy factory


    //test the saliencymap
    Object[] saliencylocation = proxy.returningFeval("runActivation",1,"tank.bmp",1);
    System.out.println(saliencylocation[0]);

    //Disconnect the proxy from MATLAB
    //proxy.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212467/how-to-call-a-user-defined-matlab-from-java-using-matlabcontrol-jar

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rich. I checked the post and tried to run the code, but it still opens every new Matlab sessions. I guess I still miss something..

Comment: I've never used matlabcontrol so can't offer more suggestions.  The example in the code called addpath and then ran a script in that directory.  The example could only work if all commands were being executed in one persistant matlab session.  That's why I thought it was the solution you were looking for.  Don't know why you got a downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I did, hope it helps

```
MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
    .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
    .setHidden(true)
    .setMatlabLocation(null).build(); 

    MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
    MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. One more question is that this code worked well for previously opened Matlab sessions by matlabcontrol (so, it does not open every new session, and work on just one opened session!), but when I used this code to open a 'new' Matlab session at the first, Matlab only showed a command window rather than workspace, current directory, etc. Did you also encounter this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Matlab Engine directly instead of Matlab Control.

Answer (score 0):

```
MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options = new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                 //.setPort(2100)
                .build();           

MatlabProxyFactory factory=new MatlabProxyFactory(options );
MatlabProxy proxy=factory.getProxy();
proxy.disconnect();//this is very important
```