# Exception in MatlabControl when running MATLAB function outside MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I need help to connect between Java and MATLAB via [MatlabControl](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) .

firstly i wanted to test code in walkthrough but every time i got same exception  :

myfunc.m :

```
function myfunc()
    disp('hello from MYFUNC')
end
```

Java:

```
class ShowImage {

 public static void main(String[] args)
        throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
    {
         // create proxy
         MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options =
            new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true)
                .build();
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

        // call builtin function
        proxy.eval("disp('hello world')");

        // call user-defined function (must be on the path)
        proxy.eval("addpath('E:\\vm')");
        proxy.feval("myfunc");
        proxy.eval("rmpath('E:\\vm)");

        // close connection
        proxy.disconnect();

}}
```

and here's exceptions :

```
Exception in thread "main" matlabcontrol.MatlabConnectionException: Could not launch MATLAB. Command: [matlab, -r, javaaddpath 'C:\Users\walaa\Desktop\matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabClassLoaderHelper.configureClassLoading(); javarmpath 'C:\Users\walaa\Desktop\matlabcontrol-4.0.0.jar'; matlabcontrol.MatlabConnector.connectFromMatlab('PROXY_RECEIVER_42dd44d9-815e-41ad-bec9-e469718b5710', 2100);]
    at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.createProcess(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:305)
    at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.requestProxy(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:116)
    at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:134)
    at matlabcontrol.MatlabProxyFactory.getProxy(MatlabProxyFactory.java:81)
    at ShowImage.main(ShowImage.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "matlab": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at matlabcontrol.RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.createProcess(RemoteMatlabProxyFactory.java:292)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

I don't know what's the problem, any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7212651/97160). Obviously it is tested and working, just make sure that MATLAB is on the Windows path (the error message suggests that it cannot find the program "matlab.exe")

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank u very much :) now it's opening matlab from java , but do u know if i can pass image path to matlab from java via MatlabControl and vice versa or not ?? cause i'm making java GUI to match between two figures one i open on java GUI and another one output from matlb matching functions ,,,please if u can guide me a little  bit in MatlabControl functions cause i'm new to it ,,,thanks again .

Comment: @user1318251: try passing the image name when you call your MATLAB function in the line: `proxy.eval("myMatlabFunction('/path/to/image.png')");`

Comment: i did what u told me but i got this error "Error using eval
Undefined function 'hgr' for input arguments of type 'char' " and my matlab function is

Comment: can u help me here i asked new question about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279998/matlabcontrol-error-using-eval-undefined-function-getinput-for-input-argumen