# Error using eval in matlabcontrol

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-deployment

I used [MatlabConrol](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) to connect Java and MATLAB. I want to send an image path to MATLAB to process it with matching functions and give me back a number of similar images and paths, to show in the Java GUI.

I always get the same error when passing an image path to MATLAB:

```
Error using eval
Undefined function 'getinput' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

Here's my MATLAB function:

```
function matlab = getinput(input)
results = hgr(input);
```

And my Java code:

```
imag = ImageIO.read(fileChoose.getSelectedFile());
ImagePath = fileChoose.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

public void SendingMatlabControl() throws MatlabConnectionException,
  MatlabInvocationException {
  // create proxy
  MatlabProxy proxy;
  // Create a proxy, which we will use to control MATLAB
  MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory();
  proxy = factory.getProxy();
  // Display 'hello world' like before, but this time using feval
    try {
      // call builtin function
      proxy.eval("getinput('imagepath')");
      // call user-defined function (must be on the path)
      proxy.eval("addpath('E:\\vm')");
      proxy.feval("matlab");
      proxy.eval("rmpath('E:\\vm)");
    } catch (MatlabInvocationException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Disconnect the proxy from MatLab
    proxy.disconnect();
  }
```

Comment: Your comment 'call builtin function' seems to suggest that `getinput` is a builtin function, but I couldn't find any mention of it on the MathWorks website.  Are you sure this is a builtin function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me give an example of calling a function, passing it input, and retrieving the output. There are two ways, either:

- use [`eval`](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html#eval%28java.lang.String%29) and assign the result of the function inside the MATLAB workspace, then retrieve those variables using [`getVariable`](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html#getVariable%28java.lang.String%29), or
- use [`returningFeval`](http://matlabcontrol.googlecode.com/svn/javadocs/doc/matlabcontrol/MatlabProxy.html#returningFeval%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to evaluate the function with its inputs, and directly retrieve the output.

Suppose we had a MATLAB function **`myfunc.m`** that takes a string as input, and returns a cell array containing a string, a number, and a vector:

```
function out = myfunc(str)
    out = cell(3,1);
    out{1} = sprintf('Welcome to %s!', str);
    out{2} = 99;
    out{3} = rand(10,1);
end
```

Here is the Java code:

```
import matlabcontrol.*;

public class TestMyFunc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws MatlabConnectionException, MatlabInvocationException
    {
        // create proxy
         MatlabProxyFactoryOptions options =
            new MatlabProxyFactoryOptions.Builder()
                .setUsePreviouslyControlledSession(true).build();
        MatlabProxyFactory factory = new MatlabProxyFactory(options);
        MatlabProxy proxy = factory.getProxy();

        // call function and get output cell array
        String in = "Stack Overflow";
        Object[] out = proxy.returningFeval("myfunc", 1, in);

        // extract stuff from cell array
        out = (Object[]) out[0];
        String str = (String) out[0];
        double x = ((double[]) out[1])[0];
        double[] arr = (double[]) out[2];

        // show result
        System.out.println("str =\n " + str);
        System.out.println("x = \n " + x);
        System.out.println("arr =");
        for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" " + arr[i]);
        }

        // shutdown MATLAB
        //proxy.feval("quit");

        // close connection
        proxy.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I get the output:

```
str =
 Welcome to Stack Overflow!
x =
 99.0
arr =
 0.5974901918725793
 0.3353113307052461
 0.29922502333310663
 0.45259254156932405
 0.42264565322046244
 0.35960631797223563
 0.5583191998692971
 0.7425453657019391
 0.42433478362569066
 0.42935578857620504
```

Comment: okay that's all good but now i need to firstly pass image path using feval then when all m files  will execute ,i will use returningFeval as u mentioned above to retrieve output number of image (tell me if i'm wrong )  ,,,problem i still have same exception ,do u see any problems in my code above  ,i really losing my mind :(

Comment: @user1318251: no, you use `returningFeval` to call your m-function passing image path and retrieving result at the same time. Please read the project [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/wiki/Walkthrough) and Java docs

Comment: i run your code and still have this error "Undefined function 'myfunc' for input
arguments of type 'char'." and when running your matlab function it gave me this error "Error using myfuncs (line 3)
Not enough input arguments." do you know what's the problem ?

Comment: @user1318251: `myfunc` must be on the MATLAB path. It worked for me because `matlabcontrol` starts the MATLAB session in the same working directory that contains the function file `myfunc.m`. A more general solution would be to simply set up the path at the beginning: `proxy.eval("addpath('c:\\path\to\folder')");`)

Comment: so it would be better to change location of m files to same directory where i setup MATLAB which is C directory (that's what you are saying ?)?

Comment: Not need i used proxy.eval("addpath('c:\\path\to\folder')");) in beginning and it working now , i'm afraid that returningFeval technique won't work with my m-files because i have several functions in this files i want to pass image path that it will be it's input and will call another functions that will match this image with my db images and give back another image path (can you get it ?) so it's not first function which will give back output it's next functions that will produce this output i wanted to test but now i don't have this code bc my graduation project partner working on it .