# How to call MATLAB functions in java file ? What are its basic Requirements?

Tags: java, matlab

i am new to mat-lab and i want to integrate MAT LAB code in Java file.i have installed MAT-LAB RUN TIME on my system now what is next ?  i am using LINUX OS on my system. what should i have to do ?

Comment: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~whitehouse/matlab/JavaMatlab.html Please have a look at it

Comment: i am already referring dis document but not getting initial steps  .. for starting i am looking for something like dis ..    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212467/how-to-call-a-user-defined-matlab-from-java-using-matlabcontrol-jar     but i am getting errors in this as well.

Comment: See this Video to get everything clear ...       http://in.mathworks.com/videos/deploying-matlab-algorithms-to-the-web-91464.html?form_seq=conf1008&elqsid=1428392033104&potential_use=Home&country_code=IN