# How to get MATLAB running on CMD?

Tags: java, matlab, cmd

I'm trying to run a **`.m`** file straight on CMD not on MATLAB's terminal but I'm starting to believe there's no way to do so on Windows. I found something similar but still not what I need:

```
    matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run whatever.m"
```

It starts a new screen with nothing but MATLAB's own terminal instead of just running the code on CMD like R, mySQL and other programs do.

Actually what I'm trying to achieve is to run some of MATLAB's code on Java. I'm aware there's a way to create a .jar, .dll, .exe,..., out of an **`.m`** file, but I need to do it on some other way. My idea was to get the results that MATLAB throws on CMD, but it just starts MATLAB, runs the code and I get no results on java using `ProcessBuilder`. That reads whatever would come out on the console, but as it's MATLAB's console it's not possible to get any results. That's why I need a way to run it straight on CMD.

Comment: So your question is how to have Matlab return the results output from an M-file to the command line and then exit?

Comment: Your request leads to a sort of simplified process-to-process communication, without a use of trivial / common O/S i/o redirections. There are ways to achieve this via smart-messaging alike the ZeroMQ allows. Plus there are projects alike Python-MATLAB-bridge, that benefit from ZeroMQ and adds exactly what you search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to use Java to run some Matlab code, then it was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212467/how-to-call-a-user-defined-matlab-from-java-using-matlabcontrol-jar). The `matlabcontrol`project can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/). There are also something on [undocumentedmatlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/jmi-wrapper-local-matlabcontrol-part-1) about local Matlab control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very similar to what I need, I've tested it and works, but it launches the entere Matlab before excuting the script, so it takes a long while, up to 10 seconds and I need call it tousands of times, so this way it's not that factible, on R languaje it's quite simple, actually it has no GUI unless you install one IDE, so I need a way to excute a .m file without launching the entere Matlab and get its results on Java.

Comment: it seems impossible, since you need the Matlab run-time as a required runtime environment for the "pure" .m file. That's why you have to either use MEX / jar built from java, or BUY the expensive Builder JA toolbox ^_^

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out, maybe it's the only way. :)