# Run Matlab Dll in Java programming

Tags: java, matlab, dll, javabuilders

Run *Matlab Dll* in *Java programming*
Do I need Java builder in order to run *Matlab DLL* in *Java*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/164490-how-to-create-a-dll-from-a-matlab-code) you would need either the MATLAB Coder toolbox or the MATLAB Compiler toolbox to create a DLL, and you could then use [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) to [create a wrapper around the DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997343/how-to-call-external-dll-function-from-java-code).  You would only need MATLAB Builder JA if you wanted [to generate .jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045087/matlab-builder-ja-compile-matlab-into-a-java-jar-free-version).

Comment: I have DLL files however, my doubt whether i need MATLAB builder JA in order to use those matlab DLL in my Java program